# How do I sync MySQL DB table

Tags: mysql, replication, table

I have 9 MySQL servers in different environments. One of them is in the testing server. That one will be the first server if I have to make the change.

Is there any way I can sync the table from the testing server to all other ones very quickly to ensure the column consistency? I tried MySQL replication but I don't want to sync data, I only want to sync the table.

Is there a --no-data option in the MySQL replica?

I am very new to MySQL, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If the "test" server is the "Primary" in a replication setup, then performing `ALTER` will be propagated to the "Replicas".

But that's about the only thing relating to your question.  And it does not seem like what you want.

There are some 3rd party packages that attempt to orchestrate schema changes.  (It's a non-trivial task.)